# Average power when a periodic, non-sinusoidal waveform is applied across a resistor with a given voltage across it

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis, rms

If I have a resistor across which some voltage is provided and a periodic ( non-sinusoidal and non-zero) wave of current is given to the same resistor, then what would be the average power? Do I need to add \$I_{avg}.V\$ to \$I_{rms}^2R\$ ? Because along with the RMS current the waveform is also giving a non-zero average current.[image]

Comment: It would help if you provided a schematic of the situation so we know what Iavg and Irms mean. I have a feeling the "I" in each case refers to a different current.

Comment: Is the voltage DC or is it periodic? If it is periodic, does it have the same period as the current waveform? What you need to do is write the expression for instantaneous power, then average that over one period to get the average power.

Comment: Are you familiar with the power equation for any continuous time periodic signals: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213175/equation-for-the-average-power-of-a-signal

Comment: @MituRaj that is a bit misleading. In this case, the actual power is desired. So the formula used should be the formula for the instantaneous power in the resistor. Not just V or I squared, but V squared / R or I squared * R.

Comment: The expression is for a unit ohm resistor, so it will have to be divided by \$ R \$.

Comment: @MituRaj it may be easier for the OP to write the equation of the current. In that case it would be multiplied by R.

Comment: @mkeith I have provided the schematic for the same. The solution provided is correct , just don't know that is it because a dc of 2A is added , we have taken the Iavg into account ? Had it been some other non-sinusoidal periodic wave with no dc added to it , did I need to take the Iavg into picture ?

Comment: @mkeith yes I'm getting ur point , it's the dc voltage across the resistor that is giving the Iavg*Vdc , otherwise that part would have been zero and we would have ended up getting just the RMS power.

Comment: @mkeith thanks , I didn't notice that the voltage is dc 

Comment: The way I look at this problem, you have a graph showing the current through the resistor. That is a simple, single periodic waveform. So all you need to do is calculate the RMS current. Then average power is Irms^2 x R. Average current is not needed to solve for average power. You don't need to calculate average current at all.

Comment: Umm okay ! Don't know why is it solved like that cuz the solution is correct

Answer (score 5):

> *If I have a resistor across which some voltage is provided and a
> periodic ( non-sinusoidal and non-zero) wave of current is given to
> the same resistor then what would be the average power.*

The average power is the average of the square of the voltage waveform divided by the resistance of the resistor. This boils down to calculating the RMS of the voltage, squaring it and dividing by resistance.

> *Do I need to add Iavg*V to Irms^2R ?*

No, it's just \$I_{RMS}^2\cdot R\$ because the RMS quantity defaults to containing DC and AC quantities.

> *Because along with the RMS current the waveform is also giving a
> non-zero average current.*

You are getting confused with what the RMS current is. It implicitly includes (unless otherwise stated) the steady state value of current and the AC components. However, if you have individual values for the AC RMS value and the steady state DC value then these can be combined like this: -

$$I_{RMS} = \sqrt{I_{DC}^2 + I_{AC}^2}$$

Where \$I_{AC}\$ is the RMS value of the AC-only content of the current. And, of course, the RMS AC current can be broken down into several sub-fractions based on individual sinewaves like this: -

$$I_{AC} = \sqrt{I_1^2 + I_2^2 + I_3^2....}$$

Where each of \$I_N\$ are different (or non-coherent) frequencies.

Comment: @AJN I think it should but it's probably better to say "average of the square of the voltage waveform".....

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy , I understood the point u put pressure upon , ie , I need not add up the average power since the RMS power contains both dc and ac components.